# Нет изображения в окне, pygame

Tags: python, pygame

При запуске кода должна появляться картинка, но она не появляется, просто фон.

Думал что проблема в разрешении картинки, сменил его на `34*17`, результатов не дало.

Интерпретатор ошибок не выдал. Помогите пожалуйста исправить код.

код:

```
import pygame
FPS = 60
W = 700  # ширина экрана
H = 300 # высота экрана
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

LEFT="to the left"
RIGHT="to the right"
UP="to the up"
DOWN="to the down"
STOP="stop"


pygame.init()
sc = pygame.display.set_mode((W, H))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
x = W // 2
y = H // 2
w=30
h=30
motion=STOP
image = pygame.image.load('C:\\Users\\Pavel\\Desktop\\game\\image1.jpg').convert()
while 1:
    sc.fill(WHITE)

    pygame.display.update()

    for i in pygame.event.get():
        sc.blit(image, [x, y])
        if i.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit()
        elif y==0:
            y=1
        elif i.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if i.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                motion=LEFT
            elif i.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                motion=RIGHT

            elif i.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                motion=DOWN
            elif i.key == pygame.K_UP:
                motion=UP
            elif i.mod == pygame.KMOD_LSHIFT:
                y+=50
        if motion==LEFT:
            x-=3
        elif motion==RIGHT:
            x+=3
        elif motion==UP:
            y-=3
        elif motion==DOWN:
            y+=3
    pygame.time.delay(60)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
import pygame

pygame.init()

width = 800
height = 600

boyut = (width, height)
pencere = pygame.display.set_mode(boyut)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

class Parca(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x = width /2,y = height / 2):
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.image.load("ball.png").convert()

        self.image.set_colorkey((0,0,0))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (x,y)

    def update(self, *args):
        up,down,right,left = args

        if self.rect.x > width:
            self.rect.x = 0
        if self.rect.x < 0:
            self.rect.x = width
        if self.rect.y > height:
            self.rect.y = 0
        if self.rect.y < 0:
            self.rect.y = height

        if right:
            self.rect.x += 10
        if left:
            self.rect.x -= 10
        if up:
            self.rect.y -= 10
        if down:
            self.rect.y += 10


parca1 = Parca()
all_sprites.add(parca1)

while True:

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:sys.exit()

    if keys[pygame.K_UP] or keys[pygame.K_DOWN] or keys[pygame.K_LEFT] or keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        up,down,right,left = keys[pygame.K_UP],keys[pygame.K_DOWN],keys[pygame.K_RIGHT],keys[pygame.K_LEFT]
        all_sprites.update(up,down,right,left)

    pencere.fill((255,255,255))

    all_sprites.draw(pencere)

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, но второй ответ мне подходит больше

Comment: @ПавелХуснуллин вам виднее, но я не исключаю, что спустя какое-то время вы можете изменить свое мнение.